# AWS API Gateway with VPC link not stable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I have deployed a API in AWS API gateway with VPC link which connects to a ELB endpoint. There is a EC2 instance behind ELB with Spring MVC and tomcat8. The problem is the API works not very stable. When I test it in both AWS console and Postman, 4 out 10 times, it gives a 404 error. The rest will get the correct response. When I test it using ELB endpoint URL in postman, it works perfect and never throw the 404 error. After some digging, I found out when the 404 error happens, the request even didn't reach ELB, I cannot find any trace in the ELB logs or Cloudwatch. Very appreciate for any help.

## HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

**Type** Status Report

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.32

Comment: The error seems to come from a tomcat server. Is Apache Tomcat/8.5.32 used on EC2 instances behind your ELB? If yes, then it reaches your instances.

Comment: @jogold Thanks for the help, but I didn't find any logger info in tomcat log. I wonder if there is any other way to find out if it reaches to the instance?